# Create firebase project when user log in to SaaS application

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I have seen a [firebase api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest) in which you can create firebase projects and it occurred to me for example, when a user wants to counter a SaaS, make it easier for me to create a project and connect it to their SaaS but I have the following questions:

If there are supposed to be limits to creating firebase projects in a google account, will there be a time when databases can no longer be created for new users?

If the above is true, how can this be solved?

I have seen that you can ask for more projects, but how many can I have?

I know that with firestore, I can model data and only in a database have all the information, but for example, each user may have special requirements in their system and also provide security and information saving operations that would be impossible if all information is in a single database.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**
"How many projects can you have as a developer?"  Yes, that's what I mean, having all the user bases in a single firebase google account.  For example, on a web page, the user wants to pay for the application, with firebase admin and google cloud functions, I can automatically create a project and have all the databases in a google account.  And what I want to know is if you can have multiple databases.  I have seen that you can ask google to give you permission to host several projects but, for example, can you have more than 100 projects or even 1000?  (I may never have reached that number, but in that case, I would like to know the limits that can be reached).

**Edit 2**
This first structure I have all the documents in a "universal" collection and I identify them with an id to know the user who used it.

[image: First structure]
[image: [First structure(2)]

But the second structure seems to me more organized and clean, in addition to the fact that users at no time need to share information among others. I have read that having nested collections is not good but over the years and the progress that firestore has had, this is no longer or was a problem only that the limitation is that you can only have up to 100 collections anidades but I never think to reach that quantity.

[image]

Inside of list, have all products for that user, because inside of document, only can have 1 mb of data and download 1 mb and is not the best option.

[in the firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data#subcollections) I see that it does not reveal other problems, it only says that it is difficult to delete the subcollection, but I do not allow users to do that and if I need to delete the subcollections, with the Google Cloud functions i can do it.

So, the second structure is more intuitive for me, but is the best option for that? or actually firestore is not good for this strcucutre?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear; what do you mean by *If there are supposed to be limits to creating firebase projects*? what limits - like how many projects you can have as a developer? Can you clarify *databases can no longer be created for new users*. New users for your app? Or new developers? Users sign up for your app and that's pretty much unlimited. Can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: I edited the post because the clarification is too long to comment on.

Comment: Yes you can have 100 Firebase projects, or your have have one Firebase project with 100 apps. However, *the user wants to pay for the application* is a confusing part. You would typically have an app developed and then users would download and sign up for that app, or sign up for a web app via the website. Either way, it's one app with a number of users. *if you can have multiple databases* is also confusing - what do you consider 'databases'? One project can have multiple collections (Firestore) or parent nodes (RTDB) - how do those relate back to your question?

Comment: *You would typically have an app developed and then users would download and sign up for that app* yes, but to use the application you have to pay for that for a 30-day plan and what I had in mind was to create a firebase project for each user.

Comment: *what do you consider 'databases'?* With database I mean that in each project you have a database because in a single firebase project you can have a single firestore database.

Comment: I have thought about using collections instead of creating a firebase project for each user and with an id for each user, identifying what belongs to them but with these questions I wanted to better orient myself on what it would be the best in the long term. A single-tenant app with single-tenant database or Multi-tenant app with multi-tenant databases

Comment: It's still a bit unclear. If you're developing a multi-user app, each user would have a Firebase account to be able to use the app (that's done through authentication). The app would keep each users 'space' separate through design and rules or share data when appropriate. There would be no need to create a separate Firebase project for each user - in fact, that would be a nightmare to maintain. If you are thinking multi-tenant, Firebase is currently the 'wrong' solution for that as it doesn't really have multi-tenant support.

Comment: It is true, because maintaining so many databases would be quite tedious. It occurred to me for example to have a collection for example Users, Products, Sales, etc. and each document having an id that identifies the user who did it this way would only need a database, but is the use of subcollections a good idea? for example, have a collection called User1 and within this have the Users, Products, Sales documents and have nested collections to store the documents. I edited the post to show better the database structure.

Comment: That *could* be a structure but maybe not. How your Firebase is structured is dependent on the use case; what kinds of queries will you be using? Does any data need to be shared between users like a product ID or price? Generally speaking having a *users* collection is common practice, then a collection for Products, Sales etc. Suppose these are users within a company; storing their data separately is fine but what if, as the owner, you want to know the total sales volume. Or which product sells the best? You need to look at it from a use perspective and ask yourself what data is needed.

Comment: *what kinds of queries will you be using?* I'm wrong, userId is the companyId, so companies don't share their data because they have nothing to do with each other, so a query might look like this `db.collection("${idCompany}/products/list").where("user", "==", userId);` with this query i would get the products that a certain user (employee) registered in that company. *Does any data need to be shared between users* again, I'm wrong, only the documents inside of companyId will share the data, with other companies not. So, i don't needed query between companies, only in one company.

Comment: But from his perspective, is it correct in this way that I explained before this comment?

Comment: At this point, I would suggest writing some code and develop a Firebase structure to see what works. You know you have a company, users and you will be sharing data between users within that company, or at least need to be running queries across users. Do that and post a question with code and your structure when you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your support, i am going to try if it is ok to use this structure.